# How to add Swift framework to Cordova Plugin

Tags: ios, swift, cordova-plugins

"No such module error" occurred in cordova plugin during Swift build

The current configuration is like this

[image]

The framework I want to add is like this

[image]

How to add Swift framework to Cordova Plugin?

Here are the methods I tried:

1. clean the build folder
2. delete derieve Data folder
3. change the framework's embed (embed&Sign, Do not embed => all try)